# Evaluate $\int_0^{2}\sqrt{4x + 1} \text{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate $\displaystyle\int_0^{2}\sqrt{4x + 1}~\text{d}x$

This becomes:

$\displaystyle\int_0^{2}(4x + 1)^\frac{1}2~\text{d}x$

I am not sure where to go from here, I suspect it might use the chain rule or reverse chain rule.

Comment: **Hint:** Let $u = 4 x + 1$

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_{0}^{2}\sqrt{4x+1}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $u=4x+1$ and $\text{d}u=4\space\text{d}x$.

This gives a new lower bound $u=4\cdot0+1=1$ and upper bound $u=4\cdot2+1=9$:

---

$$\frac{1}{4}\int_{1}^{9}\sqrt{u}\space\text{d}u=\frac{1}{4}\int_{1}^{9}u^{\frac{1}{2}}\space\text{d}u=$$

---

Use $\int y^{n}\space\text{d}y=\frac{y^{1+n}}{1+n}+\text{C}$

---

$$\frac{1}{4}\left[\frac{u^{1+\frac{1}{2}}}{1+\frac{1}{2}}\right]_{1}^{9}=\frac{1}{4}\left[\frac{u^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\frac{3}{2}}\right]_{1}^{9}=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{3}\left[u^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]_{1}^{9}=\frac{1}{6}\left[u^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]_{1}^{9}=\frac{1}{6}\left(9^{\frac{3}{2}}-1^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)=\frac{1}{6}(26)=\frac{13}{3}$$

Comment: Instead of giving new bounds, might it not be easier to just replace $u$ with $4x+1$?

Comment: In this example it is possible, but most integrals get complicated and that's why it's much easier to take the bounds into the new integral

Comment: Ah, I see. You said it can get complicated, but just of curiosity, is the method of replacing $u$ ever actually wrong?

Comment: @Airdish No, it is right! But notice than that you've to hold your original bounds

Answer (score 1):

A tip with these types of integrations:

Increase the power by one first, and then figure out the coefficient you need.

(Although someone has already provided the solution), this is a helpful way to do it mentally.

Answer (score 0):

Since the derivative of $(4x+1)^{3/2}$ is $6(4x+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$,
$$
\int_0^2 \sqrt{4x+1}dx =\left[\frac{1}{6}(4x+1)^{3/2}\right]_0^2.
$$